# Is it possible to write a program in Java without main() using JDK 1.7 or higher?

Tags: java, java-6, java-8

The following program will print `Hello world` when compiled with `JDK 1.6` or lower versions of `JDK`.

```
    public class A
    {
      static
      {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
```

But `JDK 1.7` or higher versions will generate a runtime error as follows when the above program is compiled.

```
    Error: Main method not found in class A, please define the main method as:
       public static void main(String[] args)
    or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

I would like to know if there is some way to compile and run a program without `main()` successfully in Java using `JDK 1.7` or higher.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. `public static void main(String[] args)` is the main entry for all Java applications. There are frameworks that *makes you believe* there's no need of this method, like a unit test executed by JUnit, but the fact is that the framework has a `main` method defined somewhere inside it, does the necessary calls for you and ends calling your code.

Comment: Your answer helped me to gain knowledge. But I have to somehow implement a program without main() since I am asked to do so.

Comment: @AbyWang I wonder which kind of boss do you have to make you do this. Anyway, you can create a web application, where the `main` method is in the application server, your application won't need a `main` method.

Comment: It was an assignment assigned to us during our training in Java. We implemented it using `static` blocks in Java since the version we were using there was jdk 1.6. But the same program was not working when I tried as home. Hence I posted this question.

Comment: Then you have the worst instructor all time and should get your money back

Comment: OK, nitpicking here, but it doesn't it necessarily have to be args

Comment: @user889742 it's a variable, so the name could be whatever you want. But `args` is the standard name for the arguments of an application (also the name implies it).

Comment: I encountered this error recently as my project was create and compiled in jdk6 and I imported it in jdk8 environment. Removing the 1.6 library and adding 1.8 library fixed it for me in a flash.